# Positioning Elements inside Polymer paper-toolbar

Tags: css, polymer, positioning, paper-elements, custom-element

By default the `paper-toolbar` element in polymer positions 
the Title and menu button to the left and the remaining elements to the right. Is it possible to position Elements in the centre of the `paper-toolbar`?

In my case i would like to centre a paper or `iron-input` to crete a search field. I am wondering if there is a simple trick to do this?

```
<paper-toolbar class="toolbar">
    <span class="title">Toolbar</span>
    <paper-input label="text input"></paper-input>
</paper-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can set the class of a tag to change its position in the paper-toolbar. Then the `middleJustify` property of the toolbar sets where you want tags with the class `middle` to be placed horizontally.

```
<paper-toolbar class="toolbar" middle-justify="center">
     <span class="title">Toolbar</span>
     <paper-input class="middle" label="text input"></paper-input>
</paper-toolbar>
```